# Cutting a string at a special character in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm searching a function to cut the following string and get all content BEFORE and AFTER

```
I need this part<!-- more -->and also this part
```

Result should be

```
$result[0] = "I need this part"
$result[1] = "and also this part"
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `explode()` function in PHP like this:

```
$string = "I need this part<!-- more -->and the other part.
$result = explode('<!-- more -->`, $string) // 1st = needle -> 2nd = string
```

Then you call your result:

```
echo $result[0]; // Echoes: I need that part
echo $result[1]; // Echoes: and the other part.
```

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that he will need to split on more than just the string `<!-- more -->`.

Comment: Yeah, in this case, `explode` is still the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with regular expressions. Somebody out there is probably crying for parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions, but without much context, I'm going to give you the best that I've got:

```
$data = 'I need this part<!-- more -->and also this part';

$result = array();
preg_match('/^(.+?)<!--.+?-->(.+)$/', $data, $result);

echo $result[1]; // I need this part
echo $result[2]; // and also this part
```

If you are parsing HTML, considering reading about [parsing HTML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php).

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). Maybe something like this:

```
<?php
$result = preg_split("/<!--.+?-->/", "I need this part<!-- more -->and also this part");
print_r($result);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I need this part
    [1] => and also this part
)
```